# coverlet does not create out put file

Tags: code-coverage

I have created a small sample application(.Netcore 1.1) and installed coverlet.
I also added a unit test project (MSTEST) to the above mention application.
when I run the bellow script in power-shell the test passes successfully but I don't get any output file.The current path in the command line is my UnitTest project.
 `dotnet test  /p:Collectcoverage=true`  `/p:coverletOutputFormat=icov /p:Covereletoutput=./Coverage.info`

Can you please advice me what is the reason for this problem? Do I need to use **.netCore 2+ version** to get output file?

Thanks